House floods in basement through egress window
This house used to run a daycare so I believe they had to put an egress window in by law. The problem is I don't believe they did it right and rushed through it because every heavy rain it floods my basement.
The window literally holds water like an aquarium. This has been going on for quite some time because they used some kind of silicone or glue to seal the bottom of this wall that leads to the bathroom shower drain. (Inspector didn't catch that among other things...shocker)
The window was also just full of a thin layer of river rock which is currently all around my house. I dug maybe two inches and found the gas line but no drain of any kind.
The water will weep through the bottom of the floor and wall where i indicated with the red circle. It also weeps through the entire wall directly below the window.
What are my options on fixing this issue? I live in the Midwest. 

The bottom is too high up to the window, so maybe dig it out a few inches.  Also there use to be clear plastic covers for window wells.  I would try a sheet of wood over it next time it is suppose to rain, to see if it will help.

@crip659 That painted board leaning up on the wall to the right of the well is actually the board that covers it. Your saying I should dig out the dirt and then replace it with rock to cover that gas line?

Look upward outdoors: where does all this flood water come from? Rather than evacuate the water after it collects in the window well, divert it earlier so that it never reaches the window well. While DIY.se is not a discussion forum, if you devise an idea for shedding or diverting the water, perhaps there'll be a question in there that we can help you answer.

It might help if you are careful around the gas line.  If flooding with a board on top, then extra drainage(costs) is probably needed. With the wall itself leaking, digging down and sealing on the outside, plus drainage might be required for a dry basement.

@crip659 also likely that drainage accommodations for the window well are insufficient, degraded, or nonexistent.  OP, per Greg's suggestion, get one of those plastic window well covers and cover the metal sheeting, then see if you still have an aquarium.

spray a whole can of flex seal in the pit, covering anything not solid metal or glass (including the dirt).
